# Where should view/template-specific data go?

Tags: ember.js

My main controller contains an array of companies, with lots of details.

I want to provide several different views which slice and summarize this data. The calculations required to summarize the data are sufficiently complex that I need to have a certain place to store them. Should I

1. Add the data manipulation methods to each **view** object, or
2. Create a new controller for each view, and add the data manipulation methods to the **controller**?

The Getting Started portion of the docs adds the number of remaining todos [to the controller](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-the-number-of-incomplete-todos/), so this makes me think I should create separate controllers for each view.

As a quick follow-up: if I go with #2, should I create many controllers which extend my original CompaniesController, so I don't have to reload any data?

Answer (score 2):

> Add the data manipulation methods to each view object

Please don't! Business logic is better suited for controllers.

> or Create a new controller for each view, and add the data manipulation methods to the controller?

Sort of, if the calculations are doing basically the same for each controller you could go with a [`Mixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html), something like this:

```
App.CalculationBase = Ember.Mixin.create({
  doHeavyCalculations: function() {
    ...
    return results;
  }
  ...
});
```

And then mix it into your other controllers like:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(App.CalculationBase, {
  // here you can then call this.doHeavyCalculations()
});

App.MyOtherController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(App.CalculationBase, {
  // here you can then call this.doHeavyCalculations()
});
```

But depending on how your setup looks like, you could also create an [`itemController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_itemController) with a baked mixin or not.

For example, assuming in your templates you are looping over the `CompaniesController` content like this:

```
{{#each company in model}}
  {{company}}
{{/each}}
```

Then the itemController approach would instantiate one separate `CompanyController` for each company item.

```
App.CompaniesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'company'
});

App.CompanyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  doHeavyCalculations: function() {
    ...
    return results;
  }
  ...
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks! If I went with mixins, should I have a parent controller which actually stores my companies? The child controllers will more or less be aggregates/filters...RevenueController, DelinquincyController, etc.